# attaching text with a same behaviour on the top of one element a flex row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have stack of dragable rows like the following. 
[image]

and I am being asked to add titles (English keyword, French Keywords) on top of input boxes. like this second image. The major challenge here is to have the title aligned with input box while the screen is resized.(so the input boxes get resized, also there is hamburger, and garbage icons that are in the game)

[image]

Here is very simplified HTML codes for one row.

```
<div class="list-row">
    <div class="handle">
        <button type="button" class="icon-button">
            <span class="sprite-grey-burger"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="stretch">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="stretch">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="delete-button">
        <span class="sprite sprite-garbage-bin-black"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

and its simplified version of css

```
draggable-list .list-row {
   display: flex;
}
.draggable-list .list-row .handle {
   cursor: move;
   display: flex;
}

.icon-button{
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  height: 38px;
}

.sprite-grey-burger {
  // css to show a burger sign
}


.draggable-list .list-row .stretch {
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-shrink: 1;
   flex-basis: 0%;
   margin: 0 0.4em;
}

draggable-list .list-row .delete-button {
   margin-left: 0.4em;
}

.sprite-garbage-bin-black {
    // css to show garbage bin
}
```

I think, there should be flex solution, maybe, a new row on the top with the same flexes?!
but I don't know how!

Comment: if it is labeling without function it is ligitim to use the `:before` pseudo-class and `content: "English Keyword"`, those can be positioned to be always afixed to the input element.

Comment: post a snippet that could produce the issue!

Comment: @user3154108: great answer, but I there is major problem with it, the whole content goes into css, while I need to handle several languages using angularsJS

Comment: Main div.stretch with position:relative. Inside div with position abolute and the text. Then play with top and left values, maybe negative.

Comment: @AliSaberi you can store the 'content' i.g. "English Keyword" in a data-attribute of the element and use `content: attr(data-content)` in the pseudo-class if that makes more sense for your setup.

Comment: @user3154108: awesome thanks.